# Behat, Mink and Selenium. How to check a checkbox?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, behat, mink

I am getting an error when trying to check a checkbox with Behat/Mink/Selenium.  Below is my setup and a description of my error.

**behat.yml**

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            goutte: ~
            selenium2: ~
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "behat/behat": "~3.3",
        "behat/mink-extension": "~2.2",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "~1.2",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "~1.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin/"
    }
```

}

**I run selenium 3.4.0 like this (including a gecko driver)**

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/home/ubuntu/path/to/geckodriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar
```

**FeatureContext Class:**

```
<?php

use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;
use Behat\Behat\Tester\Exception\PendingException;

/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext
{
}

?>
```

**The feature under test**

```
Feature: Search
    In order to use behat
    As a tester
    I need to be able to get all these componets to work!

    @javascript
    Scenario: A very simple test of behat functionality
        Given I am on "http://behat-testing.christaylordeveloper.co.uk/"
        Then I should see "MY BLOG"
        And the "#slave-para" element should not contain "Hi there"
        When I check "test-cb"
        Then the "#slave-para" element should contain "Hi there"
```

**The error**
this is the output of the test showing a mouseMoveTo error

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-7-6:~/behat-tests$ bin/behat
Feature: Search
  In order to use behat
    As a tester
    I need to be able to get all these componets to work!

  @javascript
  Scenario: A very simple test of behat functionality                # features/simple-test.feature:7
    Given I am on "http://behat-testing.christaylordeveloper.co.uk/" # FeatureContext::visit()
    Then I should see "MY BLOG"                                      # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
    And the "#slave-para" element should not contain "Hi there"      # FeatureContext::assertElementNotContains()
    When I check "test-cb"                                           # FeatureContext::checkOption()
      mouseMoveTo
      Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
      System info: host: 'ip-172-31-7-6', ip: '172.31.7.6', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-1018-aws', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
      Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver (WebDriver\Exception\UnknownCommand)
    Then the "#slave-para" element should contain "Hi there"         # FeatureContext::assertElementContains()

--- Failed scenarios:

    features/simple-test.feature:7

1 scenario (1 failed)
5 steps (3 passed, 1 failed, 1 skipped)
0m3.75s (10.46Mb)
```

If I comment-out the @javascript tag and comment-out the last step of the scenario (which involves javascript) it passes just fine.

How can I test with javascript without this mouseMoveTo error?

Thank you

**Update Number 2:**

I now have this working using chromedriver version 2.32 and selenium standalone server 3.5.3

I run the server from the command line like this:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar
```

My behat.yml is

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            goutte: ~
            selenium2: ~
            browser_name: 'chrome'
```

Answer (score 3):

For checking the checbox MinkContext already has predefined methods, such as `checkOption(optionName)` and `uncheckOption(optionName)`
Documentation says:

> - Checks checkbox with specified id|name|label|value
>
>   - Example: When I check "Pearl Necklace"
>   - Example: And I check "Pearl Necklace"

As this method is in [MinkContext](https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension/blob/master/src/Behat/MinkExtension/Context/MinkContext.php) you can use it from your `.feature` file like:

```
When I check "accept_checkbox"
```

Or in your `FeatureContext.php` file like

```
$this->checkOption('optionIdentifier')
```

[MinkContext](https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension/blob/master/src/Behat/MinkExtension/Context/MinkContext.php) link has a lot of predefined methods, check them out!

Comment: Thank you Igor.  I have added an edit to my original question.  I have a feeling my feature context class is missing some essential `use` statements because I can't use the elementary predefined methods like `When I check "cb_id"` or even things like `When I follow "link"`.  Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: @CTaylorGuitar strange because all the libraries in place, can you run behat with `behat -dl` . and if you try to call `$this->checkOption('optionIdentifier')` in your method in featureContext what type of error do you get?

Comment: I have edited the original question once more and now my situation and the error is explained more clearly I hope.  Any advice on how to check checkboxes with selenium gratefully received

Comment: Yeah that an awesone `mouseMoveTo ` error. So gecko driver does not support `mouseMoveTo ` method now, problem exactly with firefox browser, and you have 2 variants: update behat, mink, minkcontext to master version - there is a fix there or run tests in chrome browser.

Comment: sorry not minkContext but MinkSelenium2Driver needs to be updated, here is the last version with that fix [MinkSelenium2Driver](https://github.com/minkphp/MinkSelenium2Driver/blob/739b7570f0536bad9b07b511a62c885ee1ec029a/src/Selenium2Driver.php#L770)

Answer (score 0):

So after updating the question it became clear what is the problem. `mouseMoveTo` error is well known issue when using `selenium3`. This error happens only for `firefox` browser with `gecko` driver. To fix this issue you can use chrome or update the `MinkSelenium2Driver` library. Should be `master` branch of `MinkSelenium2Driver` which requires `behat/mink: ~1.7@dev`. Here is the point of the problem [MinkSelenium2Driver](https://github.com/minkphp/MinkSelenium2Driver/blob/master/src/Selenium2Driver.php#L766)
So if its ok for you to use all the latest behat versions, then composer.json could looks like this:

```
"require": {
    "behat/behat": "v3.3.1",
    "behat/mink": "v1.7.1",
    "behat/mink-extension": "v2.2",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "dev-master",
```

}

Comment: ok so I tried the Chrome option first.  I needed to switch from gecko to chrome-driver and everything seemed to be going well.  However I got the "You are using unsupported command-line flag --ignore-certificate-errors" error message.  I couldn't find a straightforward way of proceeding.  If I can fix this chrome error it seemed like a good method as the chrome browser did launch.  Then I tried your new composer file (thank you).  A load more errors.  Silly question: do I need to change the selenium stand alone server that I'm using?  Maybe switch to version 2.x to match the composer file??

Comment: About chrome - strange I didnt get such an error, maybe get the latest chrome-driver version. About updating to the last version I guess you got an error while updating - if its so - I would recommend you to do the next: 1) delete all files under /vendor directory  2) clean composer.lock file 3) run `composer update behat/mink-selenium2-driver`